# Display menu point only if there are published posts in that category

Tags: php

I have a menu point called "Jobs". This is linked to a page that contains mostly posts of a specific category (Jobs). I would like this navigation point to be visible only if in the page there are published posts. If not this menu point should not be visible.

How can I achieve this? Do I need custom code?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by a menu point? If you mean a nav menu item, then showing or hiding it based no the number of posts in a term will require custom code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @TomJNowell yes that what I meant :)
Do you have any hint for me? I mean what script can I use?